# How to quickly navigate file in NERDTree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

say, Im editing a file which is in a subdirectory of a root dir. Now I want to quickly jump to another file which is anywhere in the root by typing its partial name (that function like when pressing Shift+Ctr+R in Eclipse). Is it possible for NERDTree ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for [`Command-T`](https://github.com/wincent/Command-T) or [`ctrlp`](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim).

Comment: I did use ctrlp but it seems to search everywhere not in the root scope.

Comment: This depends on the value of `g:ctrlp_working_path_mode`. See `:h ctrlp` for an explanation. You can set it to `1` to use the current directory as "root" if you want and only use `:CtrlPRoot` when you want to search for a file in your project.

Answer (score 5):

NERDTree has no searching capabilities beyond `/foo` and `?bar`.

I'd second CtrlP, which kev mentioned, that does what you want (and more) very well. I love it.

But you can also use Vim's native

```
:e ../**/foo*<Tab>
```

Answer (score -1):

Setting custom keymaps can help achieve speed, here is example of my keymaps for NVIMtree:

```lua
 keymap.set("n", "<leader>ee", "<cmd>NvimTreeToggle<CR>", { desc = "Toggle file explorer" }) -- open
 keymap.set("n", "<leader>ec", "<cmd>NvimTreeCollapse<CR>", { desc = "Collapse file explorer" }) -- close


<leader> = space bar
```

from 'normal' mode -

space + ee opens file tree

space + ec closes file tree

On top of that, plugins like  "ThePrimeagen/harpoon": https://github.com/theprimeagen/harpoon will help with speed with files

With harpoon you can easily navigate files from different directories and jump back and fourth with ease

Mark and Grapple are also the names of two alternatives, but I only use harpoon

If your're new to neovim, "nvim-lazyman" will give access to a ton of neovim  configurations that are useful for testing and finding what you like, then you can implement such into your own configuration

nvim-lazyman repo: https://github.com/doctorfree/nvim-lazyman

nvim-lazyman website: https://lazyman.dev/  - all configs are also hosted, worth checking out

Comment: what is the relation between harpoon and nerdtree?

Comment: OP asked how to quickly navigate files in NERDtree. There is no opinionated way to do this in neovim. This is the reason the neovim community has developed several plugins to help uses who want to be fast in the file tree. Harpoon, Mark, Grapple all solve this problem, and all have easy opinionated implementations for users to use. This is the relationship between NERDtree, speed.